# How to design an RF frontend for an FM receiver

Tags: rf, impedance-matching, receiver, frequency-modulation, low-noise-amplifier

I'm designing a RF receiver for FM Radio. I simulated the circuit in LTspice and got an output as shown below:

[image]

This is OK, but I would like the gain to be 24 dB across the range of 88-108 MHz.

The component values I chose for the amplifier are through trial and error, and I'm not sure if the input impedance I calculated is right. How can I calculate these values, and make a more stable amplifier with low noise?

Schematic:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's simulation circuit lacks a source resistance \$R_S\$ at left, and lacks a load resistance \$R_L\$ at right. For a broadcast band FM receiver, Rs might be 75 ohms. Adding these resistances will make it more difficult to achieve 24 dB gain.

For low noise, data sheet suggests biasing at 2mA collector current.

You may be able to boost gain somewhat by raising collector impedance above 75 ohms. This is risky, because transistors often become unstable when impedance is too high. A wide band bifilar transformer on the collector can allow the collector to see 300 ohms while RL is 75 ohms:
[image: wideband rf amplifier]

Nevertheless, gain of ~16 dB is not as high as you'd like. However, gain *is* high enough that Q1's noise figure would nearly establish the receiver's overall noise performance. LTspice suggests that with Rs=75 ohm, Q1 is almost impedance-matched to Rs - that's promising.

---

Edit:
OP's bias method from a +12V DC supply could be adapted to achieve 2mA collector current. The transformer could be wound with 3 turns of bifilar magnet wire on a FT23-43 toroid core:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNGE3u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How did you get the value for the biasing resistor (R2)? According to ohms law, if I use 12V and a 6K resistor, then I should get 2mA of current, right? Also, how do you measure the input and output impedance?

Comment: I would not recommend that 180k bias method - it is too dependent on transistor HFE. In this case, it was appropriate for LTspice's 2SC3837 model, yielding 2mA. About input Z...I saw that V2's voltage had fallen in half at Q1's base, indicating that Rs = transistor's base impedance. Q1's collector is mis-matched to the 300 ohms transformed by L1:L2. This is done on purpose to keep this amplifier stable.  See the added edit to my answer

Answer (score 1):

> *I would like the gain to be 24dB from the range of 88-108MHz*

This won't happen with the 2SC3837 because it has a transition frequency of only 1.5 GHz. That's the point when the current gain falls to unity and, you need current gain to achieve voltage gain. So, the transition frequency is a little less than 15 times greater the upper frequency of operation and, because current gain falls linearly with frequency, we can predict that the current gain at 100 MHz is a bit less than 23.8 dB.

OK there are a few tricks that can be done such as resonating the input with an LC but, I don't think you will quite reach what you desire with that transistor. Try going for a BJT with an \$f_T\$ of 5 GHz.

Comment: fT is defined by current gain; there is plenty of power gain left at higher frequencies if the output (load) impedance is higher than the input (base / r_pi) resistance.

Comment: So, @TimWilliams are you criticizing my answer in some way or just confirming what I am saying. Please be clear because at the moment it looks like you are attempting to make a spoiler.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "spoiler", could you explain? Regarding gain: you say "*current gain [is needed] to achieve voltage gain*", which is true when the source and load impedances are equal. There seems ample opportunity however, to match both input and output impedances in this system. The limiting factor is not current gain, but gain-bandwidth; and since BW is only 20MHz, quite a lot of gain is available. (To put a finer point on it: the critique is that you've made an assumption without stating it (fixed impedances).)

Comment: You appear to have a habit of writing comments (to me at least) using a terse short-hand style that often comes across as a veiled criticism (or spoiler). Your follow-up comment was perfectly clear.